# JavaにC#のLazyクラスに相当するものはありますか？

Tags: java

Java8を使って開発しています。
C#には遅延初期化の仕組みとしてLazyクラスが存在しますが、Javaに同様のクラス、あるいは何らかの言語機能等は存在しますか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache Commonsの1つであるCommons-langに、LazyIntializatorクラスがあります。

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/concurrent/LazyInitializer.html

文字通り"遅延初期化"を実現しています。

Comment: ありがとうございます。抽象クラスということは、C#のLazy<T>と同じ感覚で使うなら、無名内部クラスとして使うのかな。